# How to determine the cause of an intermittent firebase cloud function error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have two different cloud functions that are both occasionally having the same error.

One is a firestore trigger to aggregate some counters and one is a scheduled task to clean up old data.

I can't seem to see any pattern to the errors and there is not a lot of information.  Also I didn't find much on here or with a google search.
It only occurs occasionally maybe every few days or up to a couple of weeks with no error.  It occurs roughly less than 2% of the time the function is run.

I am relatively new to firebase and using async await so it could be related to that (async/await).
Error and code for one of the functions below.

```
{ Error
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:45)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  code: 13,
  details: '',
  metadata: Metadata { options: undefined, internalRepr: Map {} } }
```

```
export const clearOldAvailabilityInternal = async () => {
  const limit = 500;
  let vehicleAvailabilityIds: string[] = [];  
  let vehicleTypeAvailabilityIds: string[] = [];
  const now = new Date();
  const twoWeeksAgo = moment(now).subtract(14, "days");

  do {
    vehicleAvailabilityIds = [];
    const batch1 = db.batch();
    const vehicleAvailabilityDocs = await db.collection('vehicleAvailability')
      .where('dateInterval', '<', twoWeeksAgo.toDate())
      .limit(limit)
      .get();

    for (const doc of vehicleAvailabilityDocs.docs) {
      vehicleAvailabilityIds.push(doc.id);
    };
    for(const id of vehicleAvailabilityIds) {
      const deleteRef = db.doc(`vehicleAvailability/${id}`)
      batch1.delete(deleteRef);
    }

    try {
      const result = await batch1.commit();
      console.log('Deleted ' + vehicleAvailabilityIds.length + ' vehicleAvailability documents');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
  while (vehicleAvailabilityIds.length === limit)

  do {
    vehicleTypeAvailabilityIds = [];
    const batch2 = db.batch();
    const vehicleTypeAvailabilityDocs = await db.collection('vehicleTypeAvailability')
      .where('dateInterval', '<', twoWeeksAgo.toDate())
      .limit(limit)
      .get();

    for (const doc of vehicleTypeAvailabilityDocs.docs) {
      vehicleTypeAvailabilityIds.push(doc.id);
    };
    for(const id of vehicleTypeAvailabilityIds) {
      const deleteRef = db.doc(`vehicleTypeAvailability/${id}`)
      batch2.delete(deleteRef);
    }

    try {
      const result = await batch2.commit();
      console.log('Deleted ' + vehicleTypeAvailabilityIds.length + ' vehicleTypeAvailability documents');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
  while (vehicleTypeAvailabilityIds.length === limit)

  console.log('clearOldAvailabilityInternal complete');
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

**EDIT:**

By catching the error where it occured and logging it I got some more details in the note field. "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"  I then found the answer below.

```
 { Error
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:45)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  code: 13,
  details: '',
  metadata: Metadata { options: undefined, internalRepr: Map {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

Comment: Looks like is an issue with firebase.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it is current know issue with Firestore.  Possibly with Firebase Admin v8.
They are attempting to resolve it but it "may take some time".

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/536

2 Aug 2019:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/536#issuecomment-517461545

> Our backend team believes that they know what the root cause is, but
>   it might take quite a while for the issue to be fixed in all
>   production environments.

12 Oct 2019:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/536#issuecomment-541130536

> We are continuing to improve the libraries used in our network stack,
>   but you might still experience occasional network issues even with the
>   latest @grpc/grpc-js module.